# How to restrict zone transfers to specific authorized servers only

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, named-conf

I recently failed a PCI compliance scan because of the following:

> This DNS server allows unrestricted zone transfers. Attackers may be
>   able to use this information to gain knowledge on the structure of
>   your networks to aid in device discovery prior to an actual attack.

And the suggested solution is as follows:

> Reconfigure this DNS server to restrict zone transfers to specific authorized servers only.

I am running a dedicated Linux Centos server.

My understanding is that I have to edit the /etc/named.conf file, which I have done and the the relevant part is as follows:

```
options {
    acl "trusted" {
        127.0.0.1; 
            xxx.xxx.xxx.001; //this is one of the server's ip's
            xxx.xxx.xxx.002; //this is another server's ip
    };

    allow-recursion { 
        trusted;
    };
    allow-notify { 
        trusted;
    };
    allow-transfer { 
        trusted;
    };
};
```

I then restarted the named service `/etc/rc.d/init.d/named restart` and requested a re-scan, which failed again for the same reason.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: OK, I think I may have found the problem: the acl{} tab should not be under options, but its own tab. Resubmitting for scan...lets hope

Comment: You can try to initiate a zone transfer from different hosts using `dig -tAXFR @your_nameserver example.com` or `nslookup` and the `ls example.com` command. You will see yourself when they are allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Check the rest of your config file (which you did not post here) to make sure that allow-transfer is not being overridden by the zone configuration in question.